# How do I run a Virtual Box Virtual Machine as a service in Windows 7 without any other software?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

I am trying to run a virtual machine in virtual box as a service, meaning virtual box has to start and load the virtual machine immediately after windows 7 (host operating system) loads.  The problem is that most solutions I am seeing require extra software to be downloaded.  Also there are multiple users on the host machine and I want the same virtual machine running at all times regardless of login.  So, without downloading extra software, how can this be done?  I'm thinking vmbox headless, but I'm not sure about this and I am also uncertain how to set it up.

Note:  This needs to be done without downloading extra software.  I already have the virtual machine working with a normal start of the Virtual Box, but I need to be able to have it running for different users of the same host machine.

Update:  I realize now that the problem itself is actually multiple problems that having a virtual machine run as a service would solve (simplest solution if feasible).  In light of that, let me break down the problem into its parts:
For each user, despite virtual box being installed for everyone, the virtual machines themselves are loaded from private user folders.  I tried to change this by changing the settings on Virtual box, but it would need to be changed for every user it appears based on results.  Since we have a lot of users and are constantly adding and removing them (and I don't have access to most of the accounts anyway), this isn't a good solution.
Copying the virtual machine file into the different user accounts is not viable as it eats up storage resources.
At one point, I suggested making a publicly available Virtual Machine user account that everyone could log into for the sole purpose of turning on the virtual machine if it wasn't already on and then switching to their user account after it was on, skipping this process and simply logging into their own account if it is already on.  However, this is undesirable due to the "any user can access this account" nature.  Is there a way to perhaps automate a login at boot but automatically switch user once logged in?

I guess I started with "running as a service" because that seemed the simplest, but if there is another solution, I will welcome it.  I still think that

Comment: To my knowledge, the only software capable of doing this is Microsoft Hyper-V. All other software need some kind of tool to make it start VM's at windows startup.

Comment: Hyper-V is present.  The virtual machine wouldn't work at all without enabling it.

Comment: Oracle VirtualBox is not the same as Hyper-V. HyperV is another software package.

Comment: I have hyper-v.  Certain features of VirtualBox/VMware will not work without it.

Comment: Know this because when I first used the VirtualBox, the VM wouldn't start until I enabled Hyper-V.

Comment: Are you sure you’re not confusing the hardware virtualization BIOS switch (sometimes called Hyper-V for whatever reason) with Hyper-V (which *will prevent* VirtualBox from running 64-bit guests)?

Comment: Actually I might.  That said, does hyper-v need to be downloaded?  If so its a non-starter.

Comment: Actually, as far as I can tell, they are the same thing.  They are both hypervisors.

Comment: Hyper-V is a Windows feature.  It's available in Windows 10, but not in Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

You can use VBox VM headless and won't need extra software, but there is a caveat to consider:
When the host reboots/shuts down you won't get a clean shutdown of the VM. It just is force-ably killed. That may or may not be a problem. Only you can decide on that.

How to do it:
Make a BAT or CMD file with the headless command to start the VM.
Place a CD command before that so you establish the working directory yourself. You can't really on any specific folder being set as working dir when you start the BAT file through a service.
(You may have to add the full path to the headless command too. Don't rely on the PATH variable being properly set.)

From a command-prompt you can now use the standard **SC** command to convert this BAT file into a service. (Run **SC /?** for help.)

Actually you can put the VM headless command line directly into the service with the SC command, but it can get very tricky to get it right because in many situations you need to supply multiple parameters having spaces in them, which can get complicated. Using a BAT or CMD as intermediary is easier.

After the service has been created you can furhter fine-tun eit by editing the BAT file and by modifying the service (either through the normal Services Control Panel or via the SC command).

PS. Don't forget to allow the ports for the headless instance on the Windows firewall or you still can't connect to it :-)

Comment: Not familiar with headless commands...

Comment: @cluemein VIrtualBox comes with an excellent manual. Read it.

Comment: Windows Services need to have special interfaces. A batch script cannot be a service, and neither can your run-of-the-mill executable.

Comment: @DanielB are you saying that the above solution will not work?

Comment: That’s how it is.

Comment: @DanielB well then, how do I do it?  The link you provided isn't a solution either because it requires me to download another tool.  As stated this has to be done without any other software other than what windows 7 already comes with.  Powershell scripts, bat files, alterations to registries even are viable solution methods here, but anything that requires something to be downloaded is not.

Comment: @cluemein You *cannot* do it without third-party tools. Windows services are special. VirtualBox isn’t one. The end. You could try using the Task Scheduler, but that may come with its own set of problems and also does not provide graceful shutdown.

Comment: @DanielB Pretty sure its not "The end" no offense.  I am certain there is a scripting solution to this or something similar, perhaps using a tool that comes with virtual box in conjunction with scripts.  For instance, I know tasks can be scripted into the startup by altering configuration settings, etc. etc.  I did something similar with some other programs, but different parameters were needed (it was so long ago that I did anything like this though).  I am currently working on using a combination of scripts, bat files, and config settings to achieve this. If it works, I will post it here.

Comment: Let me perhaps clarify something:  it isn't so much necessary to run it as a service as it is to simply have it start automatically and be the same virtual machine for all user accounts.  That might change the situation slightly I think.